# Asp.net Same button to edit and Save using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have something like that,
[image: A UI Look]

When I click on edit, It populate the record of that student back to Text Boxes. I want to use the same 'Save' button to save and edit. I am also saving the student through same button.
I want that when someone click the edit button Save ajax call would not call. I am stuck on that. Currently when i edit the record, same record also inserted. If anyone want to see the code I can edit the question for that .
Thanks

```
function UpdateStudent(id, name, fname, roll, age, phone, address) {
debugger
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#students").show();
    $("#txtName").val(name);
    $("#txtFatherName").val(fname);
    $("#txtRollNo").val(roll);
    $("#txtAge").val(age);
    $("#txtPhone").val(phone);
    $("#txtAddress").val(address);
    if (id) {
        $("#btnSave").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            debugger
            var Name = $("#txtName").val();
            var FatherName = $("#txtFatherName").val();
            var RollNo = $("#txtRollNo").val();
            var Age = $("#txtAge").val();
            var Phone = $("#txtPhone").val();
            var Address = $("#txtAddress").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "StudentManagement.aspx/UpdateStudent",
                data: "{'ID': '" + id + "','Name':'" + Name + "','FatherName':'" + FatherName + "','RollNo':'" + RollNo + "','Age':'" + Age + "','Phone':'" + Phone + "','Address':'" + Address + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger
                    $("#txtName").val("");
                    $("#txtFatherName").val("");
                    $("#txtRollNo").val("");
                    $("#txtAge").val("");
                    $("#txtPhone").val("");
                    $("#txtAddress").val("");
                    $("#students").hide();
                    var array = data.d;
                    $("#table").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                    for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
                        var row = "<tr>"
                        + "<td>" + array[i].ID + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + array[i].Name + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + array[i].FatherName + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + array[i].RollNo + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + array[i].Age + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + array[i].Phone + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + array[i].Address + "</td>"
                        + "<td><a href='#' onclick='UpdateStudent(\"" + array[i].ID + "\",\"" + array[i].Name + "\",\"" + array[i].FatherName + "\",\"" + array[i].RollNo + "\",\"" + array[i].Age + "\",\"" + array[i].Phone + "\",\"" + array[i].Address + "\")'>Edit</a></td>"
                        + "<td><a href='#' onclick='DeleteStudent( " + array[i].ID + " )'>Delete</a></td>"
                        + "</tr>"
                        $("#table").append(row);
                    }
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    debugger
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }
})
```

}

And Insert Student code it below, also

```
function InsetStudent() {
debugger
$(document).ready(function () {
    var Name = $("#txtName").val();
    var FatherName = $("#txtFatherName").val();
    var RollNo = $("#txtRollNo").val();
    var Age = $("#txtAge").val();
    var Phone = $("#txtPhone").val();
    var Address = $("#txtAddress").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "StudentManagement.aspx/CreateStudent",
        data: "{'Name':'" + Name + "','FatherName':'" + FatherName + "','RollNo':'" + RollNo + "','Age':'" + Age + "','Phone':'" + Phone + "','Address':'" + Address + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            debugger
            $("#txtName").val("");
            $("#txtFatherName").val("");
            $("#txtRollNo").val("");
            $("#txtAge").val("");
            $("#txtPhone").val("");
            $("#txtAddress").val("");
            $("#students").hide();
            var array = data.d;
            $("#table").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                var row = "<tr>"
                + "<td>" + array[i].ID + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + array[i].Name + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + array[i].FatherName + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + array[i].RollNo + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + array[i].Age + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + array[i].Phone + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + array[i].Address + "</td>"
                + "<td><a href='#' onclick='UpdateStudent(\"" + array[i].ID + "\",\"" + array[i].Name + "\",\"" + array[i].FatherName + "\",\"" + array[i].RollNo + "\",\"" + array[i].Age + "\",\"" + array[i].Phone + "\",\"" + array[i].Address + "\")'>Edit</a></td>"
                + "<td><a href='#' onclick='DeleteStudent( " + array[i].ID + " )'>Delete</a></td>"
                + "</tr>"
                $("#table").append(row);
            }
        },
        error: function (response) {
            debugger
            alert(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
})
```

}

And insertStudent call on jquery load, like

```
$("#btnSave").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    InsetStudent();
})
```

Comment: Yes obviously we want to see the code.. Without that we cannot get any idea to help you out..

Comment: Do you have any required field in this form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like:

**STEP1:**

If you have any required field in your form then use this

```
$("#btnSave").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    if(Check value of required field not null or empty)
    {
       UpdateStudent(id, name, fname, roll, age, phone, address);
    }
    else
    {
          InsetStudent();
    }
});
```

**STEP2:**

If you are not using any required field in your form then use hidden field. default value of this Hidden field will be `false`. When user will click on edit first assign `true` to hidden field.

```
 $("#btnSave").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    if(Check value of Hidden field true)
    {
       UpdateStudent(id, name, fname, roll, age, phone, address);
  //Here update hidden field value to false after completing the operation
    }
    else
    {
          InsetStudent();
    }
});
```

hope this logic will help you.

Comment: **step 1** help me. All the fields were required in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Remove only `btnSave click` event

```
$("#btnSave").click(function (e) {
});
```

from your `function UpdateStudent` and call the

`function UpdateStudent` directly on `edit button` click event

Comment: No man,
I cant do that, Because on removing **btnSave click** event it will automatically work without prompting me to save.

Comment: you can add that login in UpdateStudent function also